# regular expression - how to make lookahead pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to create regular expression for validation of string containing wild cards. The expression is must be in form of mobile number (`xxx-xxx-xxxx`) where `x` is digital number or question mark. In this case regexp was straight enough `^([\d?{3}]-[\d?{3}]-[\d?{4}])$` but when user requested also `*` wild card, I've been really confused.

First of all it can be `xxx-xxx-*`, right? But `xxx-xxx-**` is invalid as well as `xxx-*-*`. I read something about lookahead pattern (writing in C#) but had been only confused more. I tried to compile something like `^(?![\\*\\*])$` - "not two asterisks near one another" but it didn't work.

So, any more ideas?

Comment: If you want more information on lookahead patterns, take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood your requirement exactly but it sounds to me like you want a pattern the will match:

optionally

- one to three numbers or `?` followed by `-`
- one to three numbers or `?` followed by `-`
- one to four numbers or `?` followed by `-`

*this should match*

```
123-456
12?-4??-78??
1-3?-2?0
```

*but not match*

```
1--123
-?-23
1233-23?-234
```

*in which case you have no need for a lookahead*

this pattern should work

`^([\?\d]{1,3})(\-[\?\d]{1,3}(\-[\?\d]{1,4})?)?$`

[Try it here](http://regexr.com?2vp83)

Comment: That's right but there's still problem of wild card asterisk... I.e should match: 1*-*-*?3, 123-123-*, *1*-*1*-*2*1 etc Shouldn't match: **?-123-7777, shouldn't match at all 2 '*'s one near another...

Answer (score 0):

This would your expression with some corrections

```
^[\d?]{3}-[\d?]{3}-[\d?]{4}$
```

I moved the closing square brackets, the quantifier has to be outside of the character classes, also I removed the outermost brackets, as they don't make sense.

Now to the lookaheads.

If you want to forbid "**"

```
^(?!.*\*\*)[\d?]{3}-[\d?]{3}-[\d?]{4}$
```

I am not sure about your requirements about the usage of the "*". Is only one allowed in the string?

similar to disallow "--"

```
^(?!.*\*\*)(?!.*--)[\d?]{3}-[\d?]{3}-[\d?]{4}$
```

Comment: It seems to me it doesn't work - paired asterisks are forbidden at any part of the expression, not only at start...

Comment: Have you tried it? Because of the `.*` at the beginning of the lookahead it searches in the whole string, not only at the beginning.

Comment: OK, I read your question and my answer again. I answered only your question, on how to write a lookahead, but since your pattern is not matching a "`*`" somewhere, it will for sure not match "`123-123-*`". I updated my answer